# Convert first row into column names for mulitiple dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple data frames. In each one of them, I need to convert the 1st row into column names

My code is as follows:

### Assign all dataframes into cities

```
cities <- objects()
library(janitor)
for (i in cities){
  paste0("file_",i) <- assign(i, get(i) %>%  row_to_names(row_number = 1))
}
```

This code creates the following error:

> Error in paste0("file_", i) <- assign(i, get(i) %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1)) :
>     target of assignment expands to non-language object

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `paste0` inside thee `assign`

```
library(dplyr)
for (i in cities){
    assign(paste0("file_",i),  get(i) %>%  row_to_names(row_number = 1))
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You; however, if I "source" the entire code - it is not working. If I execute only this code chunk or if I execute the code in "Run" mode - it is working. I tried pause by Sys.sleep(1) - this also is not helping

Comment: Hi, thank you, kindly help with syntax; where exactly this piece of code to be inserted

Comment: @ksramana can you please post as a new question so that it is easier to debug

Comment: Hi, I have posted new Q; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979619/section-of-code-not-executing-in-source-mode